# Python Pandas replace NaN in one column with value from a row below of another column

Tags: python, pandas

| name | ID | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 123 | male |
| Scot | na | na |
| 124 | male | na |
| Jill | 231 | female |

I want to cut the missing values for "Scot" from the below and paste them instead of the "nan" values so the new dataframe will be thus:

| name | ID | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 123 | male |
| Scot | 124 | male |
| Jill | 231 | female |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to fix that, by changeing the way you originally load the data, because it seems you have a linebreak there. However you could do something like this:

**Test data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'John', 1: 'Scot', 2: '124', 3: 'Jill'},
 'ID': {0: '123', 1: np.nan, 2: 'male', 3: '231'},
 'gender': {0: 'male', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: 'female'}})
```

**Code:**

```
# find out which rows are valid (m) and which contain the offset data (m2)
m = df['ID'].isna()
m2 = m.shift(fill_value=False)

# create a separate dataframe, only containing the relevant row and columns for filling nan values
df2 = df[df.columns[:-1]][m2].copy()

# harmonize the index and column names so it fits the original dataframe
df2.columns = df.columns[1:]
df2.index = df2.index-1

# fill empty values by using the newly created dataframe values
df.fillna(df2)[~m2]
```

**Output:**

```
#    name   ID  gender
# 0  John  123    male
# 1  Scot  124    male
# 3  Jill  231  female
```

Comment: wow thanks! my real data set has many missing cells that needs filling. I will try to adjust to work om the real data

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html).

Here's example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-bfill/

So this should do it:

```py
df['ID'] = df['ID'].bfill()
df['gender'] = df['gender'].bfill()
```

or, if you don't need to be selective, you can run it on the entire dataframe:

```py
df = df.bfill()
```